# Android, ActionBar back button(setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)) recreates parent activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities, let's call them A and B, when I navigate to activity B using `startActivity`, within activity B I get access to the support action bar using `getSupportActionBar()` then I'm calling `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` to present as `android.R.id.home` a back button, within the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityA"
        android:label="ActivityA"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityB"
        android:label="ActivityB"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.ActivityA"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.ActivityA" />
    </activity>
```

So when I hit the hardware back button ActivityA will **NOT** be recreated, when I hit `android.R.id.home` back button ActivityA **RECREATED**, now 2 ways to fix that are:

1. override `onOptionsItemSelected` and in case it's `android.R.id.home` call `finish()`.
2. less code is using `android:launchMode="singleTop"` with ActivityA, notice that `onNewIntent` gets called.

**My question**: I don't really like the first approche, my question is about the second one, within `onNewIntent` how can I know that this specific call to `onNewIntent` is from a back button and not something else(for instance to differentiate push notifications and other calls, btw I know I can set data for the push notifications and other stuff and if there is no data then it's got to be that but anyway), do I have to override `onOptionsItemSelected` **again** and set some intent data, is there something else?